# css for display the content from top of the div

Tags: html, css

I want to display the content of all div should be begin from from.Now I have a problem with text which is display abnormal.Check the snippet and I want to display both heading 1 and heading 2 should begin from top.but heading 1 appear from top and heading 2 begin little  below.

```css
.wraper {
  
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.boxer {
  width: 25%;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="boxer b1">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.  Donec sed odio dui</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of emp div -->
  <div class="boxer b2">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of cli div -->
  <div class="boxer b3">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of doc div -->
   
</div>
<!--end of box div -->
```

edit the heading 1 content and  see the variation.I want to display it from top of the div tag.

Comment: add 
.boxer {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    min-height: 428px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 25%;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `vertical-align:top;` to `.boxer` and remove static height (`height: 175px;`) will solve your issue.

Because by default if you give `display: inline-block` then `vertical-align:baseline`;

```css
.wraper {
  
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.boxer {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="boxer b1">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.  Donec sed odio dui</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of emp div -->
  <div class="boxer b2">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of cli div -->
  <div class="boxer b3">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of doc div -->
   
</div>
<!--end of box div -->
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear but I think you need to set `vertical-align:top;` on your `inline-block` elements.

Note: I also removed the fixed heights

```css
.wraper {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.boxer {
  width: 25%;
  /*height: 175px; */
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="boxer b1">
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.Donec id elit non
      mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of emp div -->
  <div class="boxer b2">
    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of cli div -->
  <div class="boxer b3">
    <h2>Heading 3</h2>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end of doc div -->

</div>
<!--end of box div -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Add float:left in .boxer as follows

```
.boxer {
 width: 25%;
 height: 175px;
 padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: left;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
float:left;
}
```